# how can input elements be ranked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have been shaking down SO as well as the interwebs elsewhere and have not come across an answer.

I'm looking to just find basic js validation to force ranked values, 1-6 for six questions in a form.

e.g.
HTML code

```
 <form name="testform" id="testform" action="onSubmit()"> 
 <table width="357">
 <tr> 
   <td align="left" valign="top">Favorite Event/Hobby</td>
 <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
 <td width="160" align="left" valign="top"> 4th  of July<input name="Q1" type="text" id="Q1" size="4" /> </td>
 <td width="185" align="left" valign="top">       Fishing 
 <input name="Q2" type="text" id="Q2" size="4" /> 
 <br /> <br /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
 <td align="left" valign="top"><span class="style_italic">Movie night
 <input name="Q3" type="text" id="Q3" size="4" />
 </span></td>
 <td align="left" valign="top">Water Skiing/Lake 
 <input name="Q4" type="text" id="Q4" size="4" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
 <td align="left" valign="top">
  St. Patrick's Day<span class="style_italic"> 
 <input name="Q5" type="text" id="Q5" size="4" />
 </span></td>
 <td align="left" valign="top"> Golf
 <span class="style_italic"> 
 <input name="Q6" type="text" id="Q6" size="4" />
 </span></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

And then so I know some for loop or other type validation would occur. But I'm not suite sure how to create this. As an array of some kind? Just a for loop? I want to force the user to assign a value of 1-6 to each but no duplicates would be allowed.
By the way, I do not need any fancy jquery UI with this, with select box choices, etc. The look and feel here is not ideal but it will be wrapped in its own style sheet and template anyway.

I hope this makes sense, and any feedback is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class to your inputs:

```
<input name="Q1" type="text" id="Q1" size="4" class="example" />
```

Then your javascript validation could look like this (code not tested):

```
   function validation() {
       var vals = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
       var ex = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
       for (var i = 0; i < ex.length; i++) {
          var currentVal = parseInt(ex[i].value);
          if(!isInArray(currentVal , vals)){
             return false;
           }
           removeArrayElement(vals.indexOf(currentVal));
        }
         return true;
   }

    function isInArray(value, array) {
       return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
    }

    function removeArrayElement(index) {
       if (index > -1) {
          array.splice(index, 1);
       }
    }
```

Comment: This won't validate if non consecutive inputs use the same number

Comment: @DGS you are right. My tired self made a mistake. Corrected it but might still be wrong. It is not tested. Take this has pseudo-code.

Comment: I tested the updated version. You need to call `parseInt` on the value, and then it works.

Comment: @AustinMullins that makes sense. Updated my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Modifying NTRs answer to validate against all previous values instead of just the last one.

```
var usedVals = [];
var ex = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
for (var i = 0; i < ex.length; i++) {
   if(usedVals.indexOf(ex[i].value) != -1 || ex[i].value < 1 || ex[i].value > 6){
      return false;
   }
   usedVals.push(ex[i].value);
}
return true;
```

Comment: The only issue now is that the value entered could be something other than an integer.

Comment: I would say call `isNaN` on the value first. If that returns false, round to the nearest integer, and then check if that value has already been entered and is in bounds.

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend using select menus for the values in the first place to counter that issue

Comment: Thanks fellows. I'll look this over later and give it a shot and see. Many thanks to all for the feedback - Austin, DGS, NTR et al

Comment: Thank you guys, this worked perfectly, and gave me the option to add values as needed within the array. Works like a champ! Many thanks!